# Wrong value while summing floats in matlab

Tags: matlab, floating-point

```
while (tempsumf ~= sum)
        iter = iter + 1;
        tempsumf = tempsumf + fitness(iter, 1);
        if (tempsumf > sel1) 
            break;
        end 
    end
```

I have an array(fitness) of floats here (mostly with exponent -6/-5) which i am summing up in tempsumf ... now when the loop goes to the second iteration, i get the value 5.000 which is utterly wrong. I can figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to floating point precision. You shouldn't do equality or inequality tests on double precision numbers. Instead of `while (tempsumf ~= sum)`, use `while (abs(tempsumf - sum))>1e-6)` or whatever threshold you deem appropriate.

See the [MATLAB wiki entry](http://matlab.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#Why_is_0.3_-_0.2_-_0.1_.28or_similar.29_not_equal_to_zero.3F) on this topic for more information.

Second possible cause of the error: you are overwriting the built-in function `sum` with your variable `sum`. Don't do that! Call your variable `my_sum` or something similar.